# How to solve this "for loop" exercise

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexing

I have a problem that I cannot solve. Even though the output is what the exercise ask me to do, they say that the code is incorrect, that I have to use a "for loop".

This is the exercise: (the only thing provided was the array-var powerRangers)

> Iterate over the array provided in powerRangers and print to the console a string that shows the elements' index and the content of the element.
> e.g.: '0: Red'

Code:

```js
var powerRangers = ['Red', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Blue'];    
  
var cons;

for (var i in powerRangers) {

  cons = i+':';
  console.log(cons + powerRangers[i]);
    
}
```

The output that I was able to get is this:

Output:

- Code is incorrect
- There should be a for loop in your code

```
0:Red

1:Black

2:Yellow

3:Pink

4:Blue
```

This is something that I need for a course.

Comment: When asking about problems with code, always include a tag for the language being used. Please [edit] your post to add one now.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done already has a loop `for (var i in powerRangers) { ... }`. In fact, it does not need to even have any loop:

```js
var powerRangers = ['Red', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Blue'];    
powerRangers.forEach( (ranger, index) => console.log(`${index}: ${ranger}`) );
```

What 'they' would be asking for is to use a `for` loop using an index and the array length (the old way):

```js
var powerRangers = ['Red', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Blue'];    
for(var i = 0; i < powerRangers.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${i}: ${powerRangers[i]}`);
}
```

Or, if you prefer not to use back tips ([Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```js
var powerRangers = ['Red', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Blue'];    
for(var i = 0; i < powerRangers.length; i++) {
  console.log(i + ': ' + powerRangers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you Explain This code line
 `console.log(`${i}: ${powerRangers[i]}`);`

What happens with " $" ?

Comment: This is a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). `${...}` inserts the value of the contained expression (or variable) into the string.

Comment: Got it appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For **Objects** it is common to use `for in` loop but for **Arrays** you should use `for of` loop.

Here is a sample:

```js
for (let [item,index] of powerRangers.entries()) {
  console.log(`${item}:${index}`);
}
```

The `entries()` function lets you [iterate](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/array_entries.php#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20entries()%20is,instance%20of%20the%20Array%20class.) through the key/value pairs in the Array.

There are also other ways to do such a thing but I suppose you need a **for** loop.